# How to add key and its value in existing json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add key and its value in a existing json array using Javascript. I am explaining my array below.

```
var finalOut=[
            {
                "location": "Jaipur",
                "nos_of_fos": 4,
                "login_id": [
                    "9619300332",
                    "9619300347"
                ],
                "total_remarks": 0,
                "total_disposition_code": {"PTP": 3,
                    "CB": 1,"TPT":4}
            },
            {
                "location": "BHILWARA,",
                "nos_of_fos": 1,
                "login_id": [
                    "9619300346"
                ],
                "total_remarks": 4,
                "total_disposition_code": {
                    "PTP": 3,
                    "CB": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "location": "AJMER",
                "nos_of_fos": 2,
                "login_id": [
                    "9619300357"
                ],
                "total_remarks": 0,
                "total_disposition_code": {}
            }
        ]
```

Here I need if `total_disposition_code` has any value then its all key and value will add in  root object and the expected output result is given below.

```
 var result=[
                {
                    "location": "Jaipur",
                    "nos_of_fos": 4,
                    "login_id": [
                        "9619300332",
                        "9619300347"
                    ],
                    "total_remarks": 0,
                    "PTP":3,
                    "CB":1,
                    "TPT":4
                },
                {
                    "location": "BHILWARA,",
                    "nos_of_fos": 1,
                    "login_id": [
                        "9619300346"
                    ],
                    "total_remarks": 4,
                    "PTP":3,
                    "CB":1,
                },
                {
                    "location": "AJMER",
                    "nos_of_fos": 2,
                    "login_id": [
                        "9619300357"
                    ],
                    "total_remarks": 0,
                }
            ]
```

I need the above format using javascript. I have also tried the below code.

```
for(var key in finalOut){
     finalOut[key]['total_disposition_code'][key]=
    //console.log(finalOut[key]);
}
```

Comment: There's no [JSON](http://json.org) in your question. That's an array of objects -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax, and do something like this:

```
const result = finalOut.map(object => {
  if (object['total_disposition_code']) {
    const mergedObject = {...object, ...object['total_disposition_code']}
    delete mergedObject['total_disposition_code']
    return mergedObject;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 you can use the code and it will return the object you liked

`for(let i = 0; i<finalOut.length; i++) {
    a[i] = {...a[i].total_disposition_code, ...a[i]};
    delete a[i].total_disposition_code;
}`